# How to add an email forwarding in Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

In our company, some people want that all their emails are forwarded to an external email address (like gmail, for example). How is it possible to set this up in Exchange 2003 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very easy to do:

- Using Active Directory Users and Computers on a machine with the Exchange admin tools installed, create a mail-enbled contact object in the Active Directory and assign it the user's desired forwarding address ("SomeEmail@gmail.com", etc).
- Add the newly-created contact as an alternative delivery recipient on the "Exchange General" tab of the properties of the user who wants the email forwarding by clicking "Delivery Options", selecting the "Forward To" radio button, clicking "Modify", and choosing the newly-created contact from the AD. Optionally check the "Deliver messages to both forwarding address and mailbox" if you so choose.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively easy to [accomplish on Exchange](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/MF015.html).  It can also be turned on in the Outlook client with rules.

Comment: +1 For all the tutorial with pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Add a contact card for their Gmail account. Then in AD under exchange General go into delivery options and hit forward to. Choose the alias that represents the Gmail account. You could also check the box that says deliver messages to both.