# How do I forward outbound mail for a specific user in postfix?

Tags: postfix

I want to create a rule that forwards all mail with a specific sender to another email address.

From what I can tell, this might be possible with sender_bcc_maps  but I can't find any examples using a specific address, only domain matches.. additionally, the user does not exist in postfix, this is simply an outbound relay server (on a static IP, in a datacenter) for another Exchange server (on a dynamic ip, in an office).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up adding to main.cf:

```
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/outcopy
```

and then /etc/postfix/outcopy:

```
from@domain.com copyuser@anotherdomain.com
```

then ran:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/outcopy
/etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

and it is working.