# how to set up exchange 2003 to redirect emails

Tags: exchange-2003

I want to do following things:
If recipient address not exist in exchange ,redirect to a@test.com
If recipient address meet specific pattern , redirect to b@test.com
Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to implement an SMTP transport event sink (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123644(EXCHG.65).aspx for ugly details) to do what you're talking about via pattern matching. Exchange can handle redirecting mail via contact objects (as described [in this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/33261/how-to-add-an-email-forwarding-in-exchange-2003/33271#33271)), but to act dynamically (based on pattern matches, for example) you'll have to write code.